# Canvas ItemsControls item position issue

Tags: silverlight, binding, wpf-controls, itemscontrol

```
<Canvas x:Name="MainCanvas"
        Width="350"
        Height="622">
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform TranslateX="-350" />
    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Foreground="Red"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Canvas>
```

So this is what I have. However, when I bind a list to the itemscontrol, all items are placed underneath eachother.

How can I make them to spawn the first 4 on the first row, then the net 4 of the next row ?

like when I have 10 elements it should be like:

1  2  3  4

5  6  7  8

9  10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default items panel for the ItemsControl uses the `StackPanel`.  You need to get the Silverlight Toolkit and user the `WrapPanel` control in  the `ItemsControl` `ItemsPanel` template.  You will also need to give the `WrapPanel` fixed width.

Comment: Not yet had the posibility to check wether this works the way I want it to.. but atleast it showed me that it places them next to eachother.

Comment: @levisaxas:  WrapPanel will place all the items horizontally unless its width is constrained by something, then it will wrap the items to another line when it runs out of horizontal space.